# Apportionment of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me with a solution to the following please?

I have 2 tables joined together, one is an invoice header that contains an amount outstanding for an invoice and the other is the invoice lines that contain the analysis of the original amount. I need to apportion the outstanding amount against the individual original amounts so that the overall total is the total of the amount outstanding.

The code I have started with is:

```
SELECT  

  t1.TRANSACTION_REFERENCE
  ,[LINE_NUMBER]
  ,[LINE_SEQUENCE_NUMBER]
  ,t2.OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT
  ,[NET_AMOUNT]
  ,[VAT_AMOUNT]

  FROM I_DB_TRANSACTION_DETAIL_FACT t1

INNER JOIN I_DB_TRANSACTION_HEADER t2 on t1.TRANSACTION_REFERENCE =     
t2.TRANSACTION_REFERENCE
```

The results I get are:

[image]

The outstanding amount column needs to show zero in the first 4 rows and then £2351.17 and £131.44 in rows 5 and 6 respectively.

Edit:

This is the data held in the header table

TRANSACTION_REFERENCE   OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT

IN0110468843    2482.61

Edit 2:

I've used the revised code and it is returning an error:

```
(
select sum(net_amount) originalamount from I_DB_TRANSACTION_DETAIL_FACT
)
select *,case when NET_AMOUNT =0 then 0 else
NET_AMOUNT/(fn.ORIGINAL_AMOUNT * fn.OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT) end     
newoutstandingamount
from
I_DB_TRANSACTION_DETAIL_FACT T
cross apply (select * from I_DB_TRANSACTION_HEADER)fn
```

The error is:

Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: where is the original amount ?on what basis first 4 rows should be 0 and so on ?

Comment: Give us samples of the data in both tables.. it is hard to understand why the results should be as you say

Comment: Sorry, the original amount is the net amount, so because the net amount is 0 for the first 4 rows then the outstanding must be nil. The total of the original net amount is £4399.86 so if you calculate £4166.91 / £4399.86 * £2482.61 then the outstanding amount for that particular row is £2351.17.

Comment: Still hard to understand.. edit your post and add the data structure + example of input that suppose to give output as you said.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy,though you should hv thrown some sample data.
Try of your own like this,

```
;with CTE as
(
select sum(net_amount) originalamount from table1
)
select *,case when netamount =0 then 0 else
netamount/(fn.originalamount *outstandingamount) end newoutstandingamount
 from
table1 T
cross apply (select * from CTE)fn
```

in own query put this.

Comment: There is a screen shot of sample data in the original post?

Comment: I'm struggling to get this to work because the net_amount comes from table 1 and the outstanding_amount comes from table 2. Also where does the fn come from in fn.originalamount?

Comment: I've never used cross apply so just trying to work out what it does :)